# Find all functions such that $\int f(x)g(x) dx =\left(\int f(x) dx\right)\left(\int g(x) dx\right)$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, indefinite-integrals

Is it possible to find all functions such that $$\int f(x)g(x) dx =\left(\int f(x) dx\right)\left(\int g(x) dx\right)$$?

My teacher asked us to give examples to prove that this is not true but I was curious as to what nontrivial functions satisfy this. Any idea how to solve?

Thanks!!

Comment: One perhaps should be a little more precise. Do you mean, for which functions $f, g$ (say, on $\Bbb R$) is the general antiderivative of $fg$ equal to the products of the general antiderivatives of $f$ and $g$? Or for which $f, g$ is are there respective antiderivatives $F, G$ such that $FG$ is an antiderivative of g?

Comment: It is a very nice question, but it will be downvoted if you don't show any work. At least, what functions did you already find and how, and what functions can certainly not statistify? Please edit your question to include this.

Comment: Another point: what is your definition of "non-trivial"? E.g., is a constant function trivial? a linear function?

Answer (score 7):

Let $F(t) =\int f(t)dt , G(t) =\int g(t)dt $ then the your equation becomes $$\int f(t) g(t) dt = F(t) G(t) $$ and after differntiation $$F' G' =F'G+G'F $$
and hence $$1=\frac{G}{G' } +\frac{F}{F'} $$ if you take for example $$G(t) =\ln  t $$ then you obtain $$1=\frac{\ln t}{\frac{1}{t} } +\frac{F}{F'} $$ hence $$\frac{F}{F'} =1-t\ln t$$ hence $$\ln F(t) = \int \frac{1}{1-t\ln t} dt$$ thus $$F(t) =e^{\int \frac{1}{1-t\ln t} dt}.$$
So there is a lot of  pairs $(f,g) $ of functions satisfying this equation.